# SQL encryption only returning first character

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I have the following query

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET col1 = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('Key', col2) 
FROM mytable
```

when I decrypt it using

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('Key', col1)) 
FROM mytable
```

The result returned is only the first character, for example if the field contains "Computer" the result is only "C".

Comment: What data type is the column `col1` of?

Comment: column is varbinary(750)

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `VARBINARY(MAX)`? Just for the sake of testing if the resulting cipher might need more space.

Comment: Are you calling a function somewhere and have a parameter defined as `VARCHAR` only (without explicitly defining a **length** for the varchar)? In that case, the parameter defaults to a length of **exactly 1 character** which is typically *not* what you want - so you should *always* specify an explicit length for your parameters

Comment: Read this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/870f22e2-7b45-4c86-aa34-473fbfbd99b7/encrypt-servername-returns-only-first-character?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After investigation I had come to many issues so I will post what I came across, so anyone can benefit from it.

- If you changed to data type of the SQL column to varbinary then make sure that when you decrypt the data, you use the same old data type. That is if you had a column of varchar that contains data and then you changed it to varbinary, you must decrypt it using varchar, if you use nvarchar ,you will get garbage data.
- You must encrypt and decrypt using the same way. That is if you are loading the password from a stored procedure and use it in encrypting,and the SAME EXACT password is loaded using a function for decryption, u will also get garbage data (I tested it but I did not know why is this behaviour!)may be internally there is some difference between how data is returned from SP and functions.

Hope this helps anyone out there !

Comment: The Password that I thought was a String when I decrypted it was giving the same result as the question author. ( just the first letter) When I converted the Password to a Varchar first before Encrypting it,  then when I decrypted it, it was Correct. so Yes, the Decryption column or string must be Varchar

Comment: The corresponding datatype was my issue: nvarchar to varchar

Answer (score 11):

`col2` is probably nvarchar not varchar. Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('Key', col1)) 
FROM mytable
```

In nvarchar the code points for standard ASCII letters are the same as for ASCII but padded out with a `0x00` byte.

When you cast that to varchar that it is treated as a null character that terminates the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONVERT` with data type and size of the value you are encrypting updating.
Looks like `EncryptByKey` does not recognize the data properly as per column schema.

Try as below

```
ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('<Key Name>'), CONVERT(varchar(20),col1))
```